# How do I open the barred door in the Derelict Row sewers?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

There is a door in the Derelict Row sewers that clearly has an area behind it, but does not open. Is it part of a quest or do I need to find a switch/terminal? I am still in act 1.

Here is an image from the [*Deus Ex* wiki](http://deusex.wikia.com/wiki/File:2011-08-27_13.14.44.jpg), where I have **circled** the door in question:

[image: Note the gap in the lower left corner, the door is here.]

Comment: Could you provide more context or, better yet, a screenshot?

Comment: Screenshot of the map added!

Comment: Could someone tag this with `exploration`? I think that would be a good tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I remember correctly, assuming that that door is made out of bars (which I'm guessing is correct seeing as you say you can see there's stuff behind it), then it's used later on in the game as an exit back into this section of the sewers

In a quest you'll progress into the section you can see on the other side and that door will automatically be opened to give you a way out.

Comment: Note that this will not be possible until you return back to Detroit (i.e., not in Act 1).